# Unable to open docx in python

Tags: python, docx

The problem is that a file that I created with Microsoft Word 2010 but can't be opened with python. Some open and some don't. They're all created the same way. 
At first I tried to open them via path, it didn't work so I tried to do it the simple. Still no success. This is the error that I get:`docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'COMANDA_TRANSPORT_-_Grecia_SRL.docx'`

Here's my spaghetti code:

```
import os
import re
import Database
import mysql.connector as mysql
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from Database import tables


#=============================================#

# == Search for file == # 
director = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
lista_directoare = os.listdir(director)
print(lista_directoare)
print(lista_directoare.sort())
# == Last file== #
ultimul_fisier = lista_directoare[-1]
print('Last file: ' + ultimul_fisier)

def sort(fisier):
    fisier = re.search(r'\d+',ultimul_fisier).group()
    print(fisier)

string_ultimFisier = str(ultimul_fisier)
print(string_ultimFisier)

print(director + "\\" + string_ultimFisier)
#fisier = open('{}'.format(ultimul_fisier),"rb")
#fisier = open(director + "\\" + string_ultimFisier,"rb")
#document = Document(fisier)
document = Document('COMANDA_TRANSPORT_-_Grecia_SRL.docx')

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if "pip" in paragraph.text:
        print("Am gasit")
        break
    else:
        print('Nu am gasit')
        break

for table in tables:
  print(table)


document.save('test.docx')
```

Comment: Hello  Sup6, welcome to stackoverflow ! I think your question is solved here : https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/594

Comment: (which is to say, `pip install -U setuptools`, `pip uninstall -y python-docx`; `pip install -U python-docx`)

Comment: I did manage to solve the error. After doing AKX's thing and remade the docx files, it worked. Thank you!